# Infovis rGraph on demand nodes

Tags: javascript

I am using jit infovis javascript component (thejit.org). I have millions of nodes of data and need the rGraph to load on demand/ lazy load data or else it will never render. I can't find any doc on it. Does anyone know if it supports on demand loading and if so how to do it?

Many thanks

Rich

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer from the InfoVis forum. Here is the link to where it is done in a demo. All I need to do is work it out from the source.

http://demos.thejit.org/lpkgd/

Comment: Thanks, Rich, for posting that! It's exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Comment: Sorry Rich, but where did you find the source of that specific demo? I'm not finding it...

Comment: Ok, I didn't find the source of the demo as a package; but I downloaded the javascript source directly from the source of the web page. Thanks again for pointing this useful demo! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here I found the explanation of the demo, with client and server code:

http://blog.thejit.org/2008/11/02/visualizing-linux-module-dependencies/